# DataTables error using searchPanes and serverside with post ajax request

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some code that works perfectly when the Ajax request uses the `GET` method, but I need to change it to a `POST` method to avoid the following error: "400 Bad request request line is too large"

So, when I changed the get method to post, I'm getting the following error in the console:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'searchPanes' on string '{"draw":1,"columns":[{"data":null,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}, ..."

This is my code:

```
const table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    responsive: false,
    scrollX: true,
    destroy: true,
    deferRender: true,
    select: true,
    processing: true,
    searchPanes: {
        cascadePanes: true,
        viewTotal: true,
        layout: 'columns-3',
    },
    pageLength: 20,
    language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/i18n/Spanish.json',
        searchPlaceholder: "Producto | Laboratorio",
        search: "<span class='fw-bold'>Buscar:</span>",
        searchPanes: {
            title: {
                _: 'Filtros seleccionados - %d',
                0: 'No hay filtros seleccionados',
                1: 'Un filtro seleccionado'
            },
            collapseMessage: 'Ocultar filtros',
            showMessage: 'Mostrar filtros',
            clearMessage: 'Limpiar todos los filtros'
        }
    },
    ajax: {
        url: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard/products/list/`,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Token ${authToken}`},
        data: function (d) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        },
    },
    columns: columns,
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    dom: "PfBrtip",
    columnDefs: [{
        searchPanes: {
            show: true, initCollapsed: true, dtOpts: {
                dom: "tp",
                paging: true,
                pagingType: 'numbers',
                pageLength: 5,
                autoWidth: true,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollY: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
            }
        }, targets: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    },
        {
            targets: 3,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: 4,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: 5,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: 6,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: 7,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: 8,
            visible: false,
        },
        {
            targets: Array.from({length: drugstoreQuantity * 3}, (_, index) => 9 + index), className: 'text-center'
        }
    ],
    buttons: {
        // Default classes for buttons
        dom: {
            button: {
                tag: 'button', className: 'btn btn-xs',
            }
        }, // Actual buttons
        buttons: [{
            action: () => toggleConversion(),
            className: "btn btn-success m-1 text-2",
            text: '<i class="fa fa-coins"></i> &nbsp; Convertir <strong>Dólares-Bolívares</strong>',
        }, {
            className: "btn btn-primary m-1 text-2",
            text: 'Ocultar/Mostrar <strong>Días de crédito</strong>',
            action: function (e, dt) {
                const columnsToToggle = [11, 14, 17, 20];
                columnsToToggle.forEach((columnIndex) => {
                    const currentVisibility = columnVisibility[columnIndex];
                    dt.column(columnIndex).visible(!currentVisibility);
                    columnVisibility[columnIndex] = !currentVisibility;
                });
            },
        },],
    },
});
```

seems that the problem if in the data parameter inside the Ajax request, here

```
    ajax: {
        url: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard/products/list/`,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Token ${authToken}`},
        data: function (d) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        },
    },
```

seems that I cannot stringify the data before I send it to the server, but if I don't use JSON.stringify, the server doesn't receive the data of the post request.

any help? please

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object: _"An object may be returned which will be use used as the data to send to the server (therefore, if you wish to use the DataTables set parameters, you must merge them in your function), or you can add the items to the object that was passed in and not return anything from the function."_ - so I guess, returning a _string_ instead, doesn't work here.

Comment: This is your mistake: *seems that I cannot stringify the data before I send it to the server* - the `ajax:` property of datatables is not the same as `$.ajax()` - it's part of datatables, so you are not "sending it to the server" here, you are *sending it to datatables* to add its parts and datatables sends it to the server.

Comment: _"but if I don't use JSON.stringify, the server doesn't receive the data of the post request."_ - not if the script automatically sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` based on getting passed an object, but you then overwrite that with `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: The solution is to read a bit lower on the link provided above (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object) - change your `ajax: {` to `ajax: function(data, callback, settings)`  *As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request*

Comment: The alternative solution is to fix the 400 max length issue - the *better* (IMO) solution is to change it to POST, but it's likely possible to fix the 400 max url length issue.  Depends on what you're running on the server (eg asp.net is an easy fix).

Comment: Thanks guys, I haven't tried the suggestions you gave me yet but I will do so as soon as possible and I will be telling you about it. Thank you very much again))

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you so much bro, changing from `ajax: {` to `ajax: function(data, callback, settings)` was the solution. I don't know how to mark your response as the correct one but that was just perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> seems that I cannot stringify the data before I send it to the server

```
ajax: {
    url: ...
    type: 'POST',
    ...
```

The `ajax:` property of datatables is not the same as jquery's `$.ajax()` - it's part of datatables, so you are not "sending it to the server" here, you are sending it to datatables to add its parts and then datatables sends it to the server.

The solution is to provide a function callback to the `ajax:` property instead - more info in [the datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function):

> `function ajax( data, callback, settings )`
>
> *As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request*